# logstash pattern don't match in the expected way

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm using logstash to collect my server.log from several glassfish domains. Unfortunatly in the log is no domainname. But the pathname have.
So I tried to get a part of the filename to match it to the GF-domain. The Problem is, that the pattern I defined don't matche the right part.

here the logstash.conf

---

```
file {
    type => "GlassFish_Server"
    sincedb_path => "D:/logstash/.sincedb_GF"
    #start_position => beginning
    path => "D:/logdir/GlassFish/Logs/GF0/server.log"

}
grok {
    patterns_dir => "./patterns"
    match => 
    [ 'path', '%{DOMAIN:Domain}'] 
}
```

---

I' ve created a custom-pattern file and filled it with a regexp

my custom-pattern-file

---

```
DOMAIN  (?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[\/]){3}([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
```

---

And the result is:

---

```
"Domain" => "logdir/GlassFish/Logs/GF0"
```

---

I've tested my RegExp on https://www.regex101.com/ and is working fine.
Using http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to verify the pattern brings the same "unwanted" result.

What I'm doing wrong? Has anybody an idea to get only the domain name "GF0", e.g. modify my pattern or using mutate in the logstash.conf?

Comment: Post some example lines from your log file.

Comment: There is no logentry from logstash available. 
I don't think it is a problem of the input. I try to modify a variable from the conf file. But anyway here is an example line from my glasfish logfile :
 [#|2015-03-11T11:31:00.012+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.spi|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12518, TNS:listener could not hand off client connection
 ]|#]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're trying to strip out the GF0 portion from path?

If that's the case and you know that the path will always be in the same format, you could just use something like this for the grok:

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => [ 'path', '(?i)/Logs/%{WORD:Domain}/' ]
    }
}
```

not as elegant as a regexp, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you for this solution - and it works very well. The main reason to use it even it is not so elegant is, that I don't need a own pattern.